# regular expressions: match any file under a certain directory, UNLESS the leaf directory is called "script"

Tags: java, regex

I need a regular expression that will match on any file under `/path/foo`, unless the leaf directory is called `script`.  So, for example, these should match:

```
/path/foo/file.txt
/path/foo/bar/baz/file.txt
/path/foo/script/bar/file.txt <-- not the leaf directory, so this is fine
```

But these should not:

```
/path/bar/file.txt
/path/foo/bar/script/file.txt <-- leaf directory, so no match
/path/foo/script/file.txt
```

I've tried a couple things, but they all have slight issues:

1. `/path/foo/(?!.*script)/[^/]*` matches if the leaf directory CONTAINS the string "script"
2. `/path/foo(?!.*/script)/[^/]*` matches paths like `/path/foo1/script/file.txt`
3. `/path/foo/(?!.*/script)/[^/]*` matches only when there is a layer between `foo` and `script`, or if there are 2 slashes after `foo` for some reason

I can't quite get it right.  Basically, I need to put any number of `/[^/]+` after `foo`, then I can use `(?!/script)` as the negative lookahead.  How do I write that regular expression?

Comment: Something like [`^/path/foo/(?!.*/script/).*`](https://regex101.com/r/DZgfK6/1)?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew seems to work. Can you add an answer? (Also that website is great)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew actually, sorry it doesn't quite work. it fails if `script` is the next directory after `foo`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `/path/foo/baz/script/bar/file.txt` does not  match but should

Comment: Try `^/path/foo/(?!.*/script/[^/]*$).*`

Comment: @Arkadiy That is almost the same as [my answer](https://regex101.com/r/DZgfK6/3), but due to the `.*/` in the lookahead paths like `/path/foo/script/test.txt` will get matched. The `.*/` must be made optional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
^/path/foo/(?!(?:.*/)?script/[^/]*$).*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DZgfK6/2)

**Details**

- `^` - start of input
- `/path/foo/` - a literal substring
- `(?!(?:.*/)?script/[^/]*$)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if, immediately after the current location, there is

  - `(?:.*/)?` - an optional sequence of any 0+ chars, as many as possible, followed with `/` - this represents any number of subdirectories between `/path/foo` and `script/filename`
  - `script/` - a literal substring representing the `script` directory
  - `[^/]*` - any 0+ chars other than `/` representing the final file name, thus making the `script/` above a leaf directory
  - `$` - end of string finishing the file name and ensuring no other directories are on the string
- `.*` - the rest of the string.

Comment: With `(?!.*/script/)` you can't know if the eventual script folder is a leaf or not. You have to add `[^/]*$`

Comment: Actually, I noticed it doesn't quite work. It will match the regex if `script` is the next directory after `foo`.  For instance, it will match `/path/foo/script/test.txt`

Comment: @ewok I updated the answer, please add all relevant test cases to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Using a possessive quantifier to be sure to only test the leaf folder with the negative lookbehind:

```
^/path/foo/(?:[^/]*/)*+(?<!/script/).*
```

[demo](https://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyyy9aj2ar)

With the possessive quantifier `(?:[^/]*/)*+` you are sure that the last folder is reached and that the regex engine can't go back to try to succeed if the lookbehind assertion fails.

---

Also possible like that:

```
^/path/foo/(?:.*/)?+(?<!/script/).*
```

Comment: can you explain what's going on here? What's different than Wiktor's answer?

Comment: @ewok It will yield the same results as mine, just `(?:[^/]*/)*+` consumes all folders without any backtracking possible into the pattern, so, the `/script/` check is performed once and only once the folders are matched.