# regular expressions: quantifying a non-capturing group

Tags: java, regex

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51428249/regular-expressions-match-any-file-under-a-certain-directory-unless-the-leaf-d) for some background on what I'm trying to do.  In short, I want to match any paths under a `/path/foo/`, unless the leaf directory (not the leaf *file*), is `script`.

There's some answers in that quesiton that seem to work, but I'm trying to figure out why a certain solution I attempted did NOT work.  The regex is this:

```
^/path/foo(?:/[^/]+)*(?!/script)/[^/]*$
```

My admittedly limited understanding of this is the following:

1. the literal string `/path/foo`
2. any number of occurrences of the submatch `/[^/]+`. Basically, 0 or more repeated patterns of `/` followed by some directory name (I'm aware of the issues with spaces or special characters in file paths. I'm ignoring that for now)
3. NOT the literal string `/script`.  So if, after however many repeated folders from (2), the next thing is `/script`, it fails, assuming it is then followed by...
4. a literal `/`
5. 1 or more non-`/` characters, followed by the end of the string.

However, [this doesn't work](https://regex101.com/r/M99HlY/2/tests). It seems to match everything that starts with `/path/foo`.

What's wrong with this regex?

Comment: The answer is backtracking. The `*` makes it possible for the regex engines to choose other matching paths if the current attempt is failed with, e.g. the negative lookahead. Basically, always watch out for negative lookaheads after non-possessive quantifiers.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew what do you mean "choose other matching paths"? What is the other matching path that it finds?

Comment: Andreas posted an example of a valid matching path.

Answer (score 3):

Consider input:

```
/path/foo/a/b/script/file
```

Regex matches as follows:

```
^                 Ok: No text before here
/path/foo         "/path/foo"
(?:/[^/]+)*       "/a/b/script"
(?!/script)       Ok: Text after here is "/file"
/                 "/"
[^/]*             "file"
$                 Ok: No text after here
```

What you wanted is a negative lookbehind, not a negative lookahead:

```
^                 Ok: No text before here
/path/foo         "/path/foo"
(?:/[^/]+)*       "/a/b/script"
(?<!/script)      Fail: Text before here is "/script"
/                 "/"
[^/]*             "file"
$                 Ok: No text after here
```